# Создание кнопки на css

Tags: вёрстка, css

Есть меню сделанное на списках

`<ul>
 <li>1</li>
 <li>1</li>
 <li>1</li>
</ul>`

Есть кнопка вот такая - http://networkcomp.ru/button.png
Как сделать края этой кнопки на css? Т.е. ее можно просто сделать фоном у элемента `<li>`, но тогда если текст больше картинки будет получаться фигня. Интересует как разграничить левую часть и правую часть от центра.

Answer (score 1):

Как вам [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/qZa6M/)?

Используя псевдо-классы :before и :after можно добавить по краям по кусочку. Если я правильно вас понял, именно этого вам и не хватает. Если есть непонятные строчки в коде, то задавайте вопросы.

Кусочки, кстати, тоже кликабельны.

Таким способом можно создать сколь угодно сложный элемент требующией центральной части неизвестной ширины и добавок по краям известной ширины.

Смею заметить, что ваш случай достаточно простой. Вы можете просто задать фон ссылке, добавить внутреннего отступа, чтобы она стала побольше, скруглить углы и наложить теней. На все это есть CSS-свойства.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно не очень похожа, но все же =) http://jsfiddle.net/tNucM/